# How much energy is in the Universe as photons?

Tags: energy, cosmology, electromagnetic-radiation, universe

The mass of Universe in kilograms is about 10 power 53.

But how much energy exists in the Universe in form of photons?
And if they would all be converted into mass, how much mass that would make?

Dark matter and dark energy are out of the question.

Comment: You seem to be talking about the *observable* universe. We can’t observe all of it.

Comment: [Professor Marco Ajello](https://science.clemson.edu/cosmicorigins/) and his collaborators on [*A gamma-ray determination of the Universe’s star formation history*](https://science.sciencemag.org/content/362/6418/1031.full) estimate that [4e10^84 photons have escaped from stars](https://cosmosmagazine.com/physics/how-many-photons-in-the-universe-go-on-have-a-guess). How much energy that represents depends on the wavelength of those photons.

Comment: Related, possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/27799/123208

Comment: Also see https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/195920/123208

Answer (score 1):

Mass of the "observable" universe is about 10 to the power of 53. However, the answer of your question would be irrelevant, since what we have observed and measured is practically from the past. For example, the measured mass of a star in 1 billion light years from earth has added up to the calculation to get the "10 to the power of 53" number, but right now that star probably doesn't exist;  and part of it's mass has converted to photons through nuclear fusion.

Comment: Yet scientists can aproximate how much of it was converted into energy. Then they can compute how many such stars exist and compute into a result